# mouseover does not work after prepending

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using the following to prepend new tweets to the list of tweets that I currently have

```
$(newTwet).clone().hide().prependTo('#tweetsList').slideDown();
```

newTweet is a variable that holds HTML code that is coming from a POST request. Which contains

```
<div class="newTweet">.........</div>
```

Everything seems to work just fine. However, the **.newTweet** class that is being prepended to the **#tweetlist** has an associated mouseover/mouseout function that does not work until I refresh the page. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Show the code that handles the mouseover.

Comment: How are you establishing the event handler: with ".mouseover()", with ".delegate()", ".live()", ".on()" ?

Comment: With .mouseover. code is updated

Comment: See @Andrey Knupp's answer, if you add elements to the DOM you need to use live, as the they don't have the event bound to them.

Comment: @Nick No, please stop suggesting `live()`. See David's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your actual script, particularly the part that handles the `mouseover`, it's difficult to say. But I'd suggest that you need to use `on()` (or `delegate()` in jQuery versions less than 1.7):

```
$('#parentElementID').on('mouseover','.newTweet',
    function(){
        // do stuff
    });
```

Or with `delegate()`:

```
$('#parentElementID').delegate('.newTweet','mouseover',
    function(){
        // do stuff
    });
```

In jQuery 1.7 `live()` was deprecated, and replaced by `on()`, and prior to 1.7 `delegate()` is recommended:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live(). [Cited from: [jQuery API reference for `live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and effort. Indeed the right answer. Worked with me

Comment: Thank you for the accept, and I'm glad to have been of help! =)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.live('mouseover',function(){});`

Comment: Don't use `live()`; it's deprecated (which means support may/will be dropped without warning in future releases). From 1.7+ use `on()` and 1.6 and below use `delegate()`.

Comment: In fact, we have these types of questions every day. There are always a few people who only write "use `live()`" for quick rep. There are always a few who upvote these. I'm tired of commenting "no, don't use `live()`, use `delegate()`", and now I should also add "use `.on()` instead from 1.7". Could you just stop this and be more constructive?

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanation. I used on and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$(newTwet).clone(true).hide().prependTo('#tweetsList').slideDown();
```

Here is a [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) documentation.

Comment: Didn't fix the problem. Live and on where the way to go